# R how to calculate the most cases?

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid1-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using this dataset, how can I find the number of patients in the 5 countries with the most cases?

Then, how can I draw the number of patients as line graph?

Comment: 1) Please ask only one question per post. 2) Include the code that you have tried. 3) Better to add data in reproducible format using `dput` instead of external links, Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

To find the countries with most patients

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(countryName) %>%
  summarise(total = max(confirmed)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total)) %>%
  top_n(5) -> countries5

countries5
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  countryName      total
#  <chr>            <int>
#1 United States  1768116
#2 Brazil          438812
#3 Russia          379051
#4 Spain           284986
#5 United Kingdom  269127
```

To plot their `confirmed` cases evolution.

```
countries5 %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'countryName') %>% 
  select(countryCode, confirmed, day) %>% 
  mutate(day = as.Date(day)) %>%
  filter(confirmed > 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, confirmed, color = countryCode)) +
  geom_line()
```